# Angular 5 sticky menu when scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I would change menu position to fixed when menu reach top of page. here's how I proceed.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';
import { DOCUMENT } from "@angular/platform-browser";
....
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _location: Location, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc: Document) { }
  public fixed: boolean = false; 
  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    let num = this.doc.body.scrollTop;
    console.log("scroll top" , this.doc.body.scrollTop)
    if ( num > 50 ) {
        this.fixed = true;
    }else if (this.fixed && num < 5) {
        this.fixed = false;
    }
  }
```

in **HTML**

```
<div [class.menus]="fixed">
  <div class="left-menu ">
    <app-left-menu></app-left-menu>
  </div>
  <div class="second-menu" >
    <app-second-menu (display)="onDisplay($event)" [expanded]=expanded ></app-second-menu>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menus{
  position: fixed;
}
```

**The problem** is that `scrollTop` is not getting changed. when I do `console.log(this.doc.body.scrollTop)` and scroll, value is 0 and don't change.

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support? If you can get away with no IE support, the CSS `position: sticky` rule may be a good choice

Comment: it should support IE..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the body is not not the scroll container, the HTML element is

Try `document.documentElement.scrollTop`

In browsers the `document.documentElement` is a reference to the root HTML element